# window.close() stops working in node-webkit after navigating away from the main html

Tags: javascript, node-webkit

I have two html files in a prototype. If I open any of them, a closing button does the job.

```
<img  src="img/x-01.png" onclick="window.close()" />
```

After I navigate to another html, the same code sample stops working. And doesn't work even if I come back to the previous page via browser`s "back" button.

How could that be? I'm new to js, so is there some concept I don't understand?

As the code is scattered among several files, I uploaded [a stripped-down app](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/834290/test/node-webkit-sample.7z) - for observing this behaviour.

Comment: Can you provide the full code?

Comment: I don`t want to cite multiple files, so I uploaded a full windows app folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`window.close()` can only be called by the same page that opened the window in the first place (otherwise third-party web pages would be closing windows on us at will). Once you navigate away, you lose this connection and ability.

Comment: Thanks. But then, how can you close the frameless app window?

Comment: The window must close itself, i.e. with its own in-page call to window.close().